# NodeJS bot not escaping if statement

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So, I'm a bit new to coding and I'm trying to make a discord bot in NodeJS, the code seems to work fine up until the point where you type "yes" or "no", which gives the correct response but typing yes or no afterwards keeps giving the responses, when they should only be given once. It's probably a really simple problem, but I just can't figure it out.

```
  if (
msg.author.id == config.ownerID &&
msg.content.startsWith(config.prefix + "reset")
 ) {
msg.reply(
  "Are you sure you'd like to reset all inventories and nation assignments? (Reply by saying yes or no)"
);
client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.author.id == config.ownerID && msg.content.startsWith("yes")) {
    // INSERT RESET CODE HERE
    return msg.reply("All inventories and assignments have been reset.");
  } else if (
    msg.author.id == config.ownerID &&
    msg.content.startsWith("no")
  ) {
    return msg.reply("Restart aborted. Have a nice day!");
  }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new `message event` each time you run that command. This means that, it will run on every message from then on. Theres a really simple solution to this, you can simply remove that entire `message event` and implement a `message collector` instead which will only run the amount of times you want it to.

Docs: [MessageCollector](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageCollector)

```js
//Create a Message Collector that waits for 1 minute and takes in 1 message
message.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id === <Whatever IDS you want>, {max: 1, time: 60000, errors:['time'] })
//When a message is received
.then(collected => {
    //response is what message the collector received from the user
    let response = `${collected.first()}`;
    // code whatever you want to do with the user response here
    console.log(response);
})
//Will throw an error when time runs out
.catch(collected => {
    message.channel.send("Times up, no response received.");
})
```